# New line not shown in the string in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, shortcode

I am using the code to print the Title and content. Title shown first and content is shown in the next line.I wrote the code as follows

```
 $title = get_the_title( $id )."<br><br>".get_post_field( 'post_content', $id );
```

But it just prints the `<br>` tag in the output, does not break the line.

Comment: and how do you output the data?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this,

```
$title = get_the_title( $id );
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $id );
echo $title."<br>".$content;
```

or the_title();  and  the_content();

Comment: Can we give html tag inside the post title?

Comment: yes you can add html tags also simply like <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

Comment: But I also did the same just added the <br> tag in the code. But it just prints the tag, Not breaks the line.